# pylance report GeneralTypeIssues on members while typing pycurl example

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycurl, pylance

I am a python beginner learning pycurl with its example on VSCode.

```
import pycurl
from io import BytesIO

buffer = BytesIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.INTERFACE, 'lo')
c.setopt(c.URL, "http://127.0.0.1")
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
c.perform()
c.close()

body = buffer.getvalue()
print(body.decode('UTF-8'))
```

But pylance reports GeneralTypeIssues on Curl members as picture belows:
[GeneralTypeIssues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo9fD.png)

> Cannot access member "INTERFACE" for type "Curl"
> Member "INTERFACE" is unknownPylancereportGeneralTypeIssues

I don't know where I can report this issue on Pylance or pycurl so I came to Stackoverflow for help.

Much thanks for your viewing in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the problem:`c.setopt(c.INTERFACE, 'lo') c.setopt(c.URL, "http://127.0.0.1") c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)`
Think again about whether you can use `c.INTERFACE`.
c is a curl while INTERFACE is a property of pycurl.
You can try to change `c.INTERFACE` into `pycurl.INTERFACE`